# Equivalent web.config settings for WebServiceHostFactory

Tags: wcf, rest, web-config

I'm having problems finding how to setup my web.config to use the same settings as using the WebServiceHostFactory on my RESTful WCF service. Does anyone know what the equivalent web.config would look like instead of using that factory, or how I can find it (assume I should be able to attach and find the endpoint objects etc?).

I need to change a couple of small things that the factory is using, and set the authentication to none, so it will play nicely with IIS (currently getting IIS specified authentication schemes 'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication, Anonymous' - and I cant change the IIS settings).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a reference to your service in the Web.config under the system.serviceModel section.

By specifying the full name of the service implementation as the name, of the service element you can then configure it to use specific end points and behaviours.

Hope this helps.

I have used a similar config to below for controlling my WCF Rest Services.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="httpBehavior"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="serviceBinding">
            <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="{fullname of your service}">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="httpCommerceBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="serviceBinding" contract="{Service Contract full name}>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```